# Setting up a UITableViewCell NIB and Label

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I am trying to setup a label in my nib for a TableViewCell. I receive an error which comes up a bit on stackoverflow.

The error is

```
Crash: [<NSObject 0x941f4a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key displayName.
```

The issue is I am not sure If I should be connecting the Table View Cell (object) to the File's Owner. If I am, I am not sure which outlet should this be?

[image: Current Setup]

[image: Connecting view to files owner options]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some steps to success**

1. Set your own custom cell class for table view cell
2. Don't use file's owner
3. Connect all outlets to table view cell, not file's ower
4. Don't forget set reusing cell identificator

Comment: I have updated the Files Owner removing the custom class. I have then setup the Table View Cell to use the custom class instead. When completing item 3, how do I do this? I cannot ctrl drag the label to the Table View Cell ?

Comment: Did you set your class for this view? It shouldn't be named Table View Cell, should be Custom Table View or My View Cell. Of cause MyViewCell should inherited from UITableViewCell.

Comment: Yeah its a completely custom class called I can add it to the question... But I cannot drag the label to this?

Comment: You can create/drag outlets to .h file as usual or link existing outlets

Comment: As easy as that, Thank you. I had to re-drag the outlet for the reference, once i had changed the custom class to be on the Table View Cell itself rather than files owner. Thank you